# How can I draw several diagonal squares?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions

I'm the beginner in Mathematica Plot, so I recently met many situations that I could not understand. Here is my code for drawing 10 squares across the diagonal line in a square:

```
RegionPlot[{x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0 <= x <= 0.1 &&
      0 <= y <= 0.1, x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.1 <= x <= 0.2 && 0.1 <= y <= 0.2,
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.2 <= x <= 0.3 && 0.2 <= y <= 0.3,
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.3 <= x <= 0.4 && 0.3 <= y <= 0.4，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.4 <= x <= 0.5 && 0.4 <= y <= 0.5，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.5 <= x <= 0.6 &&0.5 <= y <= 0.6，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.6 <= x <= 0.7 &&0.6 <= y <= 0.7，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.7 <= x <= 0.8 &&0.7 <= y <= 0.8，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.8 <= x <= 0.9 &&0.8 <= y <= 0.9，
      x - y <= 0.1 && y - x <= 0.1 && 0.9 <= x <= 1.0 &&0.9 <= y <= 1.0},
      {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue,PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 10,
      FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(1\)]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(p\), \(2\)]\)"}, BoundaryStyle -> None]
```

But it gives me three squares:

[image]

Where are the other seven squares?

Comment: Your input data contains irregular symbol after the third square. That's why.

Comment: The `，` is wrong. Please use a suitable editor.

Comment: Yes, that's it, it's not very obvious on my laptop, but become clear in the quote mode! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

`ArrayMesh` make the task easy.

```
m = Reverse@SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {10, 10}];
m // MatrixForm
ArrayMesh[m, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {{2, ;;} -> Blue}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Or

```
ArrayMesh[SparseArray[{{x_, y_} /; x + y == 10 -> 1}, {10, 10}], 
 DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> Green, 1 -> Red}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
RegionPlot[
 y > Floor[x, 0.1] && y < Ceiling[x, 0.1], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
m = Reverse@SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 1}, {10, 10}];
MatrixPlot[m, ColorRules -> {1 -> Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice : would work with IdentityMatrix too